# A Lotus Domino Servlet gives me this error: "Cannot create a session from an agent"

Tags: java, servlets, lotus-notes, lotus-domino

I create a servlet in a Lotus Notes database on a Lotus Domino 9.0 IF5 server. The source code was taken from a tutorial page. Also, the servlet was developed in Domino Designer

This is the most important source code:

```
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;
import lotus.domino.*;
[...]

public class TestServlet extends HttpServlet {
    protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest req, HttpServletResponse res) {
    try {
        res.setContentType("text/html");        
            PrintWriter toBrowser = res.getWriter();        
            [...]
            try {    
                NotesThread.sinitThread();        
                Session s = NotesFactory.createSession();    //<== ERROR
                Database db = s.getDatabase("","names.nsf");        
                toBrowser.println(db.getTitle());        
                [...]
            }    
            catch (NotesException n) {
                System.out.println("Exception ID:  " + n.id);        
                System.out.println("Exception description:  " + n.text);
                n.printStackTrace();
            }    
            [...]
        }
        catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.println(e.getMessage());
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

When I call the servlet, I get this message on the server console.

```
13/08/2014 04:31:43   HTTP JVM: Exception ID:  4493
13/08/2014 04:31:43   HTTP JVM: Exception description:  Cannot create a session from an agent
13/08/2014 04:31:43   HTTP JVM: NotesException: Cannot create a session from an agent
13/08/2014 04:31:43   HTTP JVM:        at lotus.domino.local.Session.checkSecurityManagerExtender(Unknown Source)
13/08/2014 04:31:43   HTTP JVM:        at lotus.domino.local.Session.createSession(Unknown Source)
13/08/2014 04:31:43   HTTP JVM:        at lotus.domino.NotesFactory.createSession(Unknown Source)
[...]
```

If I write the servlet without the Lotus Notes code (Session, Database, Document, etc.) it works fine. I can do everything I want always I do not use the Lotus Domino objects. But if I add that lines, the error occurs.

What would be the problem?

TIA,

**EDIT:**

This how it looks the servlet on Domino Designer. I wrote it in a Notes DB, no outside as an standalone file.

[image: The servlet in Domino Designer]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you calling to `NotesFactory.createSession()` the user is prompted for a password as required. But it seems that there are some problem with prompting an user. So, you must manually provide the `UserName` and `Password`:

```
Session s = NotesFactory.createSession(null, "UserName", "Password");
```

Or use some another methods as mentioned in [Documentation](http://www-12.lotus.com/ldd/doc/domino_notes/rnext/help6_designer.nsf/b3266a3c17f9bb7085256b870069c0a9/5a8f8afb89d617f785256c54004d9eb4?OpenDocument), for example:

```
Session s = NotesFactory.createSessionWithFullAccess("Password");
//or
Session s = NotesFactory.createSession(null, "", "");
//or
Session s = NotesFactory.createSession(hostString, HttpServletRequest);
//etc
```

Comment: Thank you for your response. I tried with all the possibilities but none worked. With every option I get a different error message: "Older version on server does not support this method", or "Cannot create a session from an agent". I will try updating the server to 9.0.1...

Comment: @MarioSFallen How do you call your servlet?

Comment: Finally works! I had to write the servlet as a standalone file and copy the class file on the /servlet folder. I used `Session s = NotesFactory.createSession(hostString, HttpServletRequest);`. Thank you.